# Octave exponential in transfer function

Tags: octave

I am trying to figure out how to use an exponential in the transform function.  Normally the transform function is of the form tf(num, den) where num and den are linear polynomials.  I want to transform (1-exp(-Ts)/s.  I can't seem to figure out how to handle the exp(-Ts).  Any ideas?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find a specific function in Octave that handled this.  However, I found an approximation that works well.  I was going to use a Taylor series approximation.  Taylor series uses an infinite series of rational numbers to converge on a exp(-sT).  However, the Pade approximation works better and from a few papers I read this is what most people are using.  Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Did you find a good solution to this?  I am wondering whether to give up trying to get my Matlab control script working in Octave... (I don't have Matlab).